# use qt c++ set manual location and create file

Tags: c++, qt, file

I just start to study c++ and I been try to set manual location to create file, but I got some trouble here.

do you have any idea to solve this problem??

```
int main()
{
    char location;
    std::cin>>location;
    QFile file("location");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return 1;
    QTextStream out(&file);
    out << "The magic number is: " << 49 << "\n";
}
```

Comment: From my personal experience learning C++ first and afterwards start using Qt framework (if you need it) is an easier approach. Qt framework specifics can make it harder to learn C++.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have already picked up on most issues. I'd like to point out that you can use Qt's text streams to access standard input and standard output, just to keep it all Qt. It helps with the executable size if you'd like to link your project statically - you don't need to link-in the C++ streams nor string.

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    QTextStream in(stdin), out(stdout); // the input and output streams, Qt way
    out << "Enter file location: " << flush;
    QString location = in.readLine(); // this should store the file location
    QFile file(location);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return 1;
    QTextStream fout(&file);
    fout << "The magic number is: " << 49 << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems that need to be addressed.

1. use #include to include necessary header files
2. A 'char' typed variable holds only one character, e.g. 'A'. You need to use std::string or a QString.
3. To use a variable, do not enclose it in quotes. e.g. use location instead of "location".
4. always close a file after you are done with it.
5. make sure your function always returns the expected value. here it should return an integer.

So your code can be fixed to obtain this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>

int main()
{
    std::string location;
    std::cin >> location;
    QFile file(location.c_str());
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return 1;
    QTextStream out(&file);
    out << "The magic number is: " << 49 << "\n";
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable location is only one char, not string.
If you want to use Qt, so you should use its containers (QString).
Here you are trying to create file with location current_dir/location (cause of ""), but not on location stored in your var.

```
QFile file("location");
```

You have no QApplication (or QConsoleApplication) which needs by Qt.
You should start from basics of Qt apps creation.

Answer (score 0):

I would re-write your code in the following way:

```
int main()
{
    std::string location; // this should store the file location
    std::getline(std::cin, location); // read user input for file location
    QFile file(location);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return 1;
    QTextStream out(&file);
    out << "The magic number is: " << 49 << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```